# numpy argmin not returning ints on pandas objects

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to take the [`numpy.argmin`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argmin.html) of a [`pandas Series`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.html).  The numpy docs guarantee me that the `argmin` function returns an `ndarray` of ints.  However, when called on a pandas `Series`, I get an element of the index.

For example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

foo = pd.Series(np.array([1,2,3]), index=["a","b","c"])
np.argmin(foo)
```

gives back `'a'`.

Is this expected behavior?  Is there a different function that will give me the int index of the minimum argument, or do I need to include "if pandas" logic to deal with this?

Python 3.6.9 (default, Nov 25 2022, 14:10:45) [GCC 8.4.0] on linux

Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: That IS the index.  You told it the index was the three letters a, b, and c.  If you want an integer index, then don't specify a custom one.

Comment: You can always do `np.argmin(foo.to_numpy())`.

Comment: @TimRoberts sure, that *is* the index.  However, the `np.argmin` function says explicitly that it returns ints.  'a' is not an int.  Therefore, either the docs are wrong or the behavior is wrong.  Moreover, pandas recognizes that even if the index is string, sometimes we need to access/alter it by integer index, hence the existence of the `.iloc` object.  For my use case, I like to design functions that can take either numpy or pandas objects.  Usually, the same code works for both.  If I have to write "if pandas" logic, that's fine, but I prefer to avoid it when possible.

Answer (score 2):

I obtain an integer, both ways, under cPython 3.10.8.

```
>>> np.__version__
'1.23.5'
>>> 
>>> foo = pd.Series(np.array([1, 2, 3]), index=["a", "b", "c"])
>>> foo
a    1
b    2
c    3
dtype: int64
>>> 
>>> np.argmin(foo)
0
>>> foo.argmin()
0
```

The documented return value for the two forms is a little different.
It appears the `foo.argmin()` form is preferable for
your use case.

Comment: I'm a few versions back.  I guess they fixed this.  (sigh) time to deal with upgrading my python version.  :)

Comment: if this is now fixed, adding your specific versions of Pandas, NumPy, and Python into the Question may be helpful!

Comment: @Him it's probably your bumpy version which is the issue.